# OpenLayers SVG sprite externalGraphic only works in Firefox

Tags: openlayers-2, xml, svg

I am trying to set the externalGraphic property of a vector layer's style to an SVG sprite that has various viewboxes to position the icons dynamically by creating different views within my SVG file:

```
<view id="bikeview" viewBox="0 0 52 52"></view>
<view id="boatview" viewBox="52 0 52 52"></view>
```

...and then accessing them like so:

```
var defPoiStyle = {
    externalGraphic: 'images/activities/activitySprite.svg#boatview',
    pointRadius: 30,
    cursor: "pointer"
}
```

The problem is that this only works in Firefox, although with Chrome and Safari I can access each view by entering the URL directly into the browser [like this](http://040814.scltmap.appspot.com/images/activities/activitySprite.svg#boatview), just not in the map.

I have also noticed that in Chrome's network log (and likely Safari's) that the `#boatview` part of my image path gets stripped out, but not so in Firefox. I assume it is some kind of XML request issue or something, but I feel like I got my declarations right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   x="0px"
   y="0px"
   width="52px"
   height="52px"
   id="svg3753"
   version="1.1">
```

This is too complicated for jsFiddle, but [here is my map](http://040814.scltmap.appspot.com/). Give it a go in Chrome and then in Firefox, and you should see what I mean (the boat icon is what is supposed to display).

Answer (score 2):

I was unaware that support for SVG fragment identifiers is [not so hot](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fragment), so I found somewhat of a workaround in the form of Base64 encoding (thanks to these [doppnet](http://doppnet.com/2012/07/Ninja-SVG-sprites) and [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) posts).

So, after optimizing my SVG in Inkscape I converted it to base64 using [Mobilefish's converter](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php) (if you use this, make sure to set max characters per line to 0 so you don't have line breaks), and then added them as strings in a JSON array:

```
var activityURI = [
    {"activity":"All","uri":"oZWlnaH..."},
    {"activity":"Hiking","uri":"4bWxucz..."},
    ...
];
```

And then accessed them like this:

```
//for minor extra efficiency, set prefix of URI common to every item in array:
    var uriRoot = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVy...";

//set full URI using desired index:
    var uriPath = uriRoot + activityURI[//desired index# goes here\\].uri;
    var defPoiStyle = {
        externalGraphic: uriPath
    }
```

**Drawbacks**

1. Long, ugly strings in my code (thank goodness for word wrap).
2. Bigger JS file.
3. Tedious to maintain SVG since Base64 converter must be used every time.

**Benefits:**

1. It works in Chrome.
2. No more individual HTTP requests for individual SVG files. **EDIT:** not true at all! I incorrectly assumed that this method would not trigger an additional HTTP request since it is included within my JS. Back to the drawing board...
3. Base64 may be [comparable in performance](http://www.mobify.com/blog/base64-does-not-impact-data-uri-performance/) to unencoded SVG.

[Here is a working result](http://040914.scltmap.appspot.com/).

Comment: [@PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo) could you please summarize what you did in the working result mentioned in your edit?